# Cookies vs Sessions with CookieStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

In Rails 3, what is the difference between storing data in a cookie and storing data in a session, with the session store set to the default of CookieStore?

e.g.

```
cookie[:foo] = 'bar'

# MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
session[:foo] = 'bar'
```

As far as I can tell, both end up stored in a client-side cookie.

When would you choose to use one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The main difference, in Rails 3, is that when you use `cookie[:foo] = 'bar'` the user is able to see the value for the cookie, i.e. `'bar'`. When you use `session[:foo] = 'bar'` the value will be encrypted by rails and stored in the `_myapp_session` cookie.

You would use the `cookie[]` format when the information you want to store is not bound to the session, e.g. when the users selects the preferred language.

You would use the `session[]` format when you want to store information that is related to the current session, e.g. the `id` of the the user.

[From Rails 4 cookies became encrypted by default.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html)

Comment: a correction; the value is not encrypted but encoded (with base64) by default.

Comment: Although the question was about Rails 3, in which cookies were only encoded, it's worth noting that Rails 4 encrypts them.

Comment: Why does Rails 4 encrypts ? Any idea? ,
Won't it be expensive for a rails app which encrypts/decript every requests?

Comment: Hmm, is encryption really necessary? Surely what you really want is a signature, so that people can't forge it?

Comment: Sessions are encrypted because programmers don't expect session data to be visible in the client.  If you want the client to be able to see the data, put it in the cookie.

Comment: Cookies can be signed or encrypted as well (see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) On the other hand, sessions can be unencrypted (depending on configuration). What you called the "main difference" is not true entirely.

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma No worries. It is not very expensive (really difficult to find a use case when removing it would be a noticeable improvement) and is trivial to scale (no shared resources like database). Look for optimizations elsewhere.

Comment: @Cem  "since Rails 4, the default store is EncryptedCookieStore."... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage

Comment: Coming from Michael Hurtl's RoR tutorial there seems to be one more difference: Anything stored using `session` uses the `cookie_store` which by default expires after the browser closes unless you set it to some other value using the global config: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 14.days`
 . In contrast, the `cookie` method allows you to store stuff using a custom expiration date per cookie and on demand without affecting the encrypted `cookie_store` and its predefined expiration date.

Answer (score 14):

Rails provides several storage mechanisms for the session hashes. The most important are `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` and `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`.

There are a number of session storages, i.e. where Rails saves the session hash and session id. Most real-live applications choose `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` (or one of its derivatives) over file storage due to performance and maintenance reasons. `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` keeps the session id and hash in a database table and saves and retrieves the hash on every request.

Rails 2 introduced a new default session storage, `CookieStore`. `CookieStore` saves the session hash directly in a cookie on the client-side. The server retrieves the session hash from the cookie and eliminates the need for a session id. That will greatly increase the speed of the application, but it is a controversial storage option and you have to think about the security implications of it:

Cookies imply a strict size limit of 4kB. This is fine as you should not store large amounts of data in a session anyway, as described before. Storing the current user’s database id in a session is usually ok.
The client can see everything you store in a session, because it is stored in clear-text (actually Base64-encoded, so not encrypted). So, of course, you don’t want to store any secrets here. To prevent session hash tampering, a digest is calculated from the session with a server-side secret and inserted into the end of the cookie.
That means the security of this storage depends on this secret (and on the digest algorithm, which defaults to SHA512, which has not been compromised, yet). So don’t use a trivial secret, i.e. a word from a dictionary, or one which is shorter than 30 characters