# Rails unique lists dependent on sessions

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a webpage that allows users to create their own lists on the index page, and I want the list saved in their session, so each list is unique to the user.

I can't seem to get a grasp of how Rails stores sessions. Will I need to create a table to store each session and have it relate to my table of list items, or does Rails already implement sessions in a way I can use to display the list items?

I'm using Rails 5, and I'm aware the session store has been taken out and placed into a gem, but I don't know to what extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store temporary data (like RAM in a computer) with

`session[:my_data] = { name: 'foo', age: 1 }`

You can store more permanent data (like hard drive in a computer) with

`cookies[:my_data] = { name: 'foo', age: 1 }`

You can write this code in any controller.

More details about sessions and cookies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153978/9676642).

Comment: So if I set the session params as session[:list_id] = List.id , would it store a simple ordered list for unique users? Will it keep multiple id's in the session?

Comment: Yes, storing a list of integers is easy to do in session.